# How to add a red asterisk '*' before the text of a file chooser in install4j?

Tags: install4j

There is a drop list whose drop-down list entries is A and B, and a file chooser in install4j.

I want to achieve the following effect:

If I choose A, the text of the file chooser is "* File Name" where the asterisk is red.

If I choose B, the text of the file chooser is "File name".

All I can think of right now is to create two file choosers, one's text is "* File Name" and another is "File name", the screen will display different file chooser based on the content of drop list.

Then, how to set the asterisk to red for "* File Name"?
Or is there a more elegant way to add a red asterisk '*' before the text of a file chooser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a drop-down list, a label with a red asterisk and a file chooser into a horizontal group.

[image]

In the rename dialog for the label, the "custom ID" of the form component is set to "asteriskLabel", so it can be referenced more easily in a script. The "Selection script" property of the "Drop-down list" is set as shown below

[image]

The label form component has its text set to "*" and the font color to red, in addition, the "Visibility script" is set to "false", so that it is initially hidden.

[image]

When the user chooses "B" from the drop-down list, the red asterisk will be shown.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. And do you know how can an asterisk(*) be hidden or visible in front of a file chooser based on the content of another file chooser in install4j? I ask another question in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70091861/how-can-an-asterisk-be-hidden-or-visible-in-front-of-a-file-chooser-based-on.

Comment: You can do that with scripts just like shown above. The "File chooser" form component has a "Validation script" property that can be used similarly to the select script of the drop-down list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried it, I'm sorry it's not what I want.
The "Validation script" property is a little different with the "select script", the change for "select script" happens in real time, which means as long as I choose one of the items of drop-down list, change will come, and I don't need to click other button. However, for the "Validation script" property, I must click the "next" button, the asterisk will be visible. What I really want is as long as I add something to the file chooser, the asterisk for another file chooser will be visible without any other action.

Comment: Do you know how to do this?

Comment: If you use the "Browse" button, the script will be executed immediately. You can prevent manual input by deselecting the "Manual entry allowed" property of the file chooser component.

Comment: Actually, disabling "Manual entry allowed" property is a little unreasonable here in the installation process. Both of the two file chooser is optional in our product. If one of them is chosen, another is mandatory. However, the users may choose a file first, and then change their mind and decide not to choose any file, if we prevent manual input, the chosen file can't be removed in this case, which we don't want to see.  Is there any better method?

Comment: And it seems using "Reset initialization on previous" to delete the input is not friendly to me. Maybe, it's better for me to just report an error if there isn't a better way.

Comment: You can listen to focus lost changes of the text field of the file chooser by setting the "Initialization script" to `import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
configurationObject.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent focusEvent) {
        // TODO add code here
    }
});`

Comment: Thanks for your so many helps, I decide to just report an error if one of the file chooser is empty and the other isn't, thank you very much.

Comment: The "Selection change script" property of the "Drop-down list" doesn't work in console mode, does it?

Comment: Indeed, that script is just for the button in GUI mode

Comment: In console mode, is there any better way to implement the function like the "Selection change script" property of the "Drop-down list"?

Comment: You can add a "Console handler" form component directly after the "File chooser" form component for special processing